Hive - how to convert a string of complex json into an array of structs
I'm on Hive 2.7.5
I have data that looks like this in a hive table with the following structure:
Table Structure :
id - string
json_data - string
`
id   |json_data
1001 |[{"device_id":12345,"field1":"dddd","field2":1234,"serv_list":[100,200],"task_mgr":
      {"mgr_id":"1","start_ts":"2024-08-20T10:01:00.000Z"},"field3":"2322"}, 
      {"device_id":12345,"field1":"dfdd","field2":2322,"serv_list":[101,201],"task_mgr": 
      {"mgr_id":"2","start_ts":"2024-08-20T10:20:07.444Z"},"field3":"2322"}]
`

I am looking to split the array and explode it to get output like this:
id|device_id|mgr_id|start_ts
1001|12345|1|2024-08-20T10:01:00.000Z
1001|12345|2|2024-08-20T10:20:07.444Z

I tried regex and split but can't get it working.

Any help is appreciated
TIA!!
Tried using split with delimiters and regex_replace() but I'm running into issues with the pattern managing to grab accurately.

Any ideas anyone ?
